# Bootstrap rearragne columns on mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'be trying to make this work over an hour with no success...

In my Desktop version I have 3 columns like so:

A,C: col-lg-3
B: col-lg-6

```
[A][B][C]
```

and I want them to show like this on mobile devices

A,C: col-sm-6
B : col-sm-12

```
[A][C]
[  B ]
```

I' was trying with pull-left col-sm-pull-x and col-sm-push-x but my problem was that the columns remained on the same vertical position something like this

```
    [A]
    [  B ]
  [C]          -> col-sm-pull-6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achiece this, we look at the order you want the divs to appear on mobile since this is a mobile first frame work. your end result shows us that the markup should be div#a, then div#c, then div#b. from there we assign all the classes for the sizes at xs, sm, md. now we will use push and pull to re order them at the md screen width and larger.

start by creating on xs and sm

```
[A][C]
[ B  ]
```

now on md we have

```
[A][C][ B  ]
```

we need to pull B back 3 columns and push C over 6 columns at md and larger. see the below markup and fiddle

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="a" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">COL A</div>
        <div id="c" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-push-6">COL C</div>
        <div id="b" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 cold-xs-12 col-md-pull-3">COL B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the ids are not needed. see the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6933/